# Null pointer exception when calling measure on inflated layout

Tags: java, android, android-layout

So I have a layout that is a separate file, so I inflate it. Then I change my text views and image in  my layout, and call measure, but I get a null pointer when I try to measure the layout. I cannot for the life of me figure out why this is. I'm trying to convert the layout to a bitmap eventually.

```
View inflatedView  = ((Activity)getContext()).getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.my_layout, null);

inflatedView.measure(getWidth(), getHeight());
inflatedView.layout(0, 0, inflatedView.getMeasuredWidth(),inflatedView.getMeasuredHeight());
Bitmap viewAsImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(inflatedView.getWidth(), inflatedView.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas viewCanvas = new Canvas(viewAsImage);
```

Here is the XML

```
<RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:id="@+id/my_layout"
    android:background="@color/transparent_black">
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/image_left"
        android:layout_width="48dip" android:layout_height="48dip"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" android:maxWidth="48dip" android:maxHeight="48dip"
        android:padding="5dip" />
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/image_right"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dip" android:src="@drawable/arrow"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:maxWidth="48dip" android:maxHeight="48dip"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
    <TextView android:paddingLeft="4dip" android:paddingRight="1dip"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/image_left"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/image_right"       android:id="@+id/some_name"
        android:maxLines="1" android:ellipsize="end" android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textStyle="normal" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

At the measure() line, it throws a null pointer, and I have verified that getWidth and getHeight are giving legitimate values.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: give us the xml, pretty please  :)

Comment: Please post your logcat and the xml, perhaps these can further explain the error.

Comment: did you make sure that `inflatedLayout` is not null?

Comment: when are you inflating the view?  if in onCreate, you can't get the measurements yet since the view has not been been sized

Comment: i'm inflating the view manually in a method, not in onCreate because this view is not (and cannot) be part of the current view that's being used.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

`measure()` throws `Null Pointer Exception` because when you inflate you layout it won't read layout height width properties.

Just add this line before calling `view.measure()` depending upon type of layout you are using

> v.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED), MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));

```
public Bitmap getBitmapFromView(RelativeLayout v) {
        v.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        v.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED), MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
        v.layout(0, 0, v.getMeasuredWidth(), v.getMeasuredHeight());
        Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getMeasuredWidth(), v.getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
        v.draw(c);
        return b;
    }
```

Comment: thaaanks a lot.. costed me a lot of time to figure that out :)

Comment: This solution doesn't work for all devices. I ended up passing a parent when inflating the view.

Comment: @MuhammadBabar see this please http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener.html

Comment: @AZ_ Yeah this could be another option but the more easier would be passing a parent while inflating!

Answer (score 34):

The top level RelativeLayout seems to freak out on measure without boundaries.  Set explicit boundaries on the inflated view before calling measure:

```
v.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(0,0));
```

Comment: I was getting the same issue on Galaxy S3, but not on Nexus 5,4 and Galaxy S4. And this solution worked for me. Thanks

Comment: Samsung phones always give errors like this, actually this solution will work on every device which give null pointer exception in the case

Comment: Only occurred on the HTC Sensation for me, I think it is due to API level (Ice Cream) ie: anything less than Jelly Bean

Comment: this solution worked for me on Genymotion emulator with Android 4.3

Comment: It affects all versions Android 4.x but Eric's solution solves the issue. Android 5 and up handle it well without the additional code.

Answer (score 11):

`Inflater` does not extract `layout_width` and `layout_height` attributes when you don't assign its parent as an argument in `inflate` method, so try to set `LayoutParams` with specified width and height and then call measure.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you are inflating by hand, and why you want to save an image of it. But I'm doing almost the same thing in a complex layout for a home screen widget, and this is what I do:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
View content = inflater.inflate(layoutId, null);
int measuredWidth = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(widgetWidth, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY); 
int measuredHeight = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(widgetHeight, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
content.measure(measuredWidth, measuredHeight); 
content.layout(0, 0, content.getMeasuredWidth(), content.getMeasuredHeight());
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(widgetWidth, widgetHeight, Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
File file = new File(bitmapCacheFileName);              
file.createNewFile();
FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(file);
bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, ostream);
ostream.close();
```

Comment: With my code? Where do you get the NullPointerException? On what line?

Comment: See this complete code, this won't throw NullPointerException http://stackoverflow.com/a/11047006/185022

Answer (score 1):

While I found that setting layout parameters (as in several other answers) did fix my problem, the solution I used ended up being that the views were inflated with

```
inflater.inflate(layoutId, null);
```

instead of

```
inflater.inflate(layoutId, parent, false);
```

This was more correct for my use case since there was actually a parent and the layout parameters of the parent could be used and respected.

Answer (score 1):

I fix it with adding:

```
view.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(desiredWidth,desiredHeight));
```

to the view before returning it from InfoWindowAdapter.getInfoWindow

(from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15750783/4291264)

Answer (score 1):

Just found out that testing device or emulator android version < 4.4 this generates a nullpointer exception. Changing the layout with a Linear one will solve the problem.Here i changed your code.

***Code:***

```
<LinearLayout  
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="@color/transparent_black">

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/image_left"
        android:layout_width="48dip" 
        android:layout_height="48dip"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"      
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:maxWidth="48dip"
        android:maxHeight="48dip"
        android:padding="5dip" />
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/image_right"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:maxWidth="48dip"
        android:maxHeight="48dip"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
    <TextView android:paddingLeft="4dip"
        android:paddingRight="1dip"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/image_left"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/image_right"
        android:id="@+id/some_name"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textStyle="normal" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
View inflatedView  = ((Activity)getContext()).getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.my_layout, null);
```

To

```
View inflatedView  = ((Activity)getContext()).getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.my_layout, null,false);
 inflatedView.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
          RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
          RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

If crash while invoking view.measure() method using the api below android 4.3