# NullPointerException when using RelativeLayout as custom InfoWindow

Tags: android, google-maps, nullpointerexception, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm trying to use a `RelativeLayout` as custom `InfoWindow` for my markers, but a I get a `NullPointerException` every time `showInfoWindow` is called (via tapping on a `Marker` or programmatically). I'm using Google Maps Android API v2.

**Exception:**

```java
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:465)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
    at maps.a.y.i(Unknown Source)
    at maps.a.y.a(Unknown Source)
    at maps.a.w.a(Unknown Source)
    at maps.a.bd.a(Unknown Source)
    at maps.y.bw.b(Unknown Source)
    at maps.y.bw.a(Unknown Source)
    at maps.a.dh.a(Unknown Source)
    at maps.a.n.c(Unknown Source)
    at maps.a.dw.a(Unknown Source)
    at maps.a.bd.c(Unknown Source)
    at maps.a.dq.onSingleTapConfirmed(Unknown Source)
    at maps.e.v.onSingleTapConfirmed(Unknown Source)
    at maps.e.j.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
    ...
```

**My code:**

*custom_infowindow.xml*

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dip" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip"
        android:paddingRight="10dip"
        android:paddingTop="5dip"
        android:src="@drawable/icon" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/icon"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip"
        android:paddingRight="10dip"
        android:singleLine="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/snippet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/title"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/icon"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:paddingBottom="10dip"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip"
        android:paddingRight="10dip"
        android:singleLine="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

*CustomInfoWindowAdapter.java*

```java
public class CustomInfoWindowAdapter implements InfoWindowAdapter {

    private View layout;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public CustomInfoWindowAdapter(Context context) {
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
        ViewHolder holder;

        if (layout == null) {
            layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_infowindow, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.title = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.title);
            holder.snippet = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.snippet);

            layout.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) layout.getTag();
        }

        holder.title.setText(marker.getTitle());
        holder.snippet.setText(marker.getSnippet());

        return layout;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView title;
        TextView snippet;
    }

}
```

Funny thing is that if I use `LinearLayout` instead it works just fine, but I'd rather use only one `ViewGroup` if possible. And of course I would like to know what happens with that `onMeasure` throwing a `NullPointerException`.

EDIT: Also, wrapping the `RelativeLayout` inside a `FrameLayout` or a `LinearLayout` will work. Wrapping it inside another `RelativeLayout` won't, of course.

Comment: Now new google maps API v2 is available try that.

Comment: Sorry I didn't explicitly mention it: I'm actually using v2 API.

Comment: I've seen that exception happen when you try to get width or height of anything before the width is taken. Example try to get width before `super(savedInstanceState)` in `onCreate` of an Activity. Haven't worked with maps so I'm not sure what's causing it here

Comment: No @JayGridley, sorry. I finally opted for using two nested `LinearLayouts`.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I had this problem and was able to fix it by adding

```
view.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(desiredWidth,desiredHeight));
```

to the view before returning it from InfoWindowAdapter.getInfoWindow

Comment: Depending on implementation you can sometimes use 0 for width and height. For me, layout.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(0,0)); worked well.

Answer (score 24):

Just found out that in android version < 4.4 this generates a nullpointer exception. Changing the layout with a Linear one will solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks,just wrapped whole RelativeLayout into LinearLayout.

Comment: I agree, I'm seeing it on Android 4.2. It looks like `java.lang.NullPointerException
 at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:529)
 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15609)`

Answer (score 4):

I experienced this issue even when I didn't have a RelativeLayout in my xml. It turns out that my class backing the XML inherited from RelativeLayout, even though it was a LinearLayout.

It didn't cause a bug for several different devices, but when I tried on my S3 it crashed.

Anyways, just either remove or wrap the RelativeLayout or set a layout height/width first.

Comment: Great. I wrapped my original (root) RelativeLayout with a dummy new LinearLayout. It worked like magic, after days of trying. Additionally, I think it's a bug in older versions of Android, since my lollipop device worked well, but my client's 4.1.2 device threw a NullPointerException.